# Get class from Object in the run time in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, dataframe

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.type.NumericType
import org.apache.spark.sql.type.BooleanType
   ....
   ....
val TableSchema = Array(
      ("ID", IntegerType),
      ("Name", StringType),
      ("TNum", integerType),
      ("Handled", BooleanType),
      ("Value", StringType)
      )
```

I have an array of schema information of a table and I am attempting to map it to a struct that can be used in the spark dataframe creation. The array after transformation should be as below:

```
val struct = Array(
 StructField("ID", NumericType),
 StructField("Name", BooleanType),
 StructField("TNum", NumericType),
 StructField("Handled", BooleanType),
 StructField("Value", StringType))
```

So I am trying to write a method that convert each element to a StructField. This is my attempt:

```
    def mapToStruct(arr:Array[(String, String, Object)])={
     val newArr = arr.map(ele => StructField(ele._1, ele._2))
     newArr
   }
```

In this situation, I cannot get the class of `StringType`, `BooleanType` or `IntegerType` from the third parameter of method mapToStruct. Exception I got is `type mismatch; found : Object required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType`. But if I change the parameter type to Array[(String, String, DataType)], it does not match the variable type.

My question is what datatype I should choose for the third parameter of method mapToStruct and then I can get the class of this object at run time.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by " it does not match the variable type." ?

Comment: @parmu `type mismatch; found : Array[(String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.AtomicType with Product with Serializable)] required: Array[(String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)] `Note: (String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.AtomicType with Product with Serializable) <: (String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType), but class Array is invariant in type T. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as _ <: (String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.

val tableSchema: Array[(String, DataType)] = Array(
  ("ID", IntegerType),
  ("Name", StringType),
  ("Handled", BooleanType),
  ("Value", StringType)
  )

def mapToStruct(arr: Array[(String, DataType)]): Array[StructField] = arr.map(e => StructField(e._1, e._2))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you explain why type inference cannot set right datatype for tableSchema?